# Google Analytic code turns my page blank

Tags: google-analytics

So I added the google analytic code to my site and when i load the page my page returns blank, I tried posting it right before the closing "head" and also tried to put it right before the closing "body"..I still get the same result, I have done this on another site and it worked fine so I dont know whats going on...anyone has any idea?

Comment: No idea unless you can post a code snippet or a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a broken `</script>' tag.  Run the page against an HTML validator. That should help find your problem.